# How can I get the position of a child element relative to a parent?

Tags: wpf

If a have a Canvas parent, it is very easy to get the position of a child:

```
Canvas.GetLeft/Top (child)
```

But how can I get the position of a child for other types of parents?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It can be done using `TranslatePoint` method of the control.

```
UIElement container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(control) as UIElement;
Point relativeLocation = control.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), container);
```

`new Point(0, 0)` represents the top left point of the control and `TranslatePoint` will return the location of that point relative to the parent control (I assumed here the parent is a `UIElement`).
You can place instead of *container* any ancestor of the control.

Comment: I did not know about TranslatePoint. Very handy!

Comment: `Point` has a parameterless constructor which initializes to the same as `new Point(0,0)` if anyone wants to save the few characters.

Comment: `TranslatePoint` will return the location of that point relative to the target element which in this example is the container.

Comment: As of C# 7.1 you can simple use `default` instead of  `new Point(0,0)`.