# How a Rect object able to intersectwidth Rectangle object? (in WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes, rect

I have some Rectangle object at my Canvas, and one Rect which has a Move() method. I would like to do that, if my Rect intersectWith one of the Rectangle, then that Rectangle be deleted.

Something like that (rct is a Rect, rctn is a Rectangle):

```
if (rct.InterSectsWith(rctn))
   {
     rctn.Invalidate();
   }
```

What shoud i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the Rect's native IntersectsWith function and just create a new Rect From your Rectangle object.

```
rct.IntersectsWith(new Rect(rctn.Margin.Left, rctn.Margin.Top, rctn.Width, rctn.Height));
```

This assumes that rctn is a direct child of Canvas, and that it is positioned left and top. If it isn't, you can use the TranslatePoint function described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923697/how-can-i-get-the-position-of-a-child-element-relative-to-a-parent) to get the x and y coordinates relative to your Canvas.