# Drag User Control, but keep it inside the bounds of its parent in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control that I am dragging inside of a grid. The Z-Index is set pretty high so that I can keep it above the other children. Dragging the control works perfectly, but if a user wants to move the control outside of the grid it will allow it.

[image]
How do I keep it from leaving the bounds of the parent Grid control, here is what I have now:

```
   private System.Windows.Point _anchorPoint;
    private System.Windows.Point _currentPoint;
    private bool _isInDrag;

   private void UserControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
        _anchorPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
        if (element != null) element.CaptureMouse();
        _isInDrag = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void UserControl_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isInDrag) return;
        var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (element != null) element.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        _isInDrag = false;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

   private void UserControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_isInDrag) return;
            _currentPoint = e.GetPosition(null);

            UIElement container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(_parentGrid) as UIElement;
            System.Windows.Point relativeLocation = _parentGrid.TranslatePoint(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), container);

            if (_currentPoint.X > relativeLocation.X) return;
            if(_currentPoint.Y >= relativeLocation.Y)return;

            _transform.X += _currentPoint.X - _anchorPoint.X;
            _transform.Y += (_currentPoint.Y - _anchorPoint.Y);
            RenderTransform = _transform;
            _anchorPoint = _currentPoint;
        }
```

The "relativeLocation" is always 0x0, so thats not working. Any ideas would greatly be appreciated.

*Note : I know if I changed my UserControl to a Window it would mitigate all of the issues that I am having. But to be honest, it looks great this way and I really don't want to clutter the window up. This system opens up as a dashboard that consumes the user's' entire window ( is opened on a separate window). So when you open a window here, its doesn't flow right.

Comment: Looks like you're calculating the relative location of the `parentGrid` to it's container. Which would explain the zero point. Try the `UserControl` to it's container instead, ref [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1923775).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the relativeLocation. The math can be a bit annoying to get right, though. Try this approach, it worked well when I tested it:

```
    private void UserControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isInDrag) return;
        _currentPoint = e.GetPosition(null);

        //This is the change to the position that we want to apply
        Point delta = new Point();
        delta.X = _currentPoint.X - _anchorPoint.X;
        delta.Y = _currentPoint.Y - _anchorPoint.Y;

        //Calculate user control edges
        var leftEdge   = Margin.Left + _transform.X + delta.X;
        var topEdge    = Margin.Top + _transform.Y + delta.Y;
        var rightEdge  = Width + Margin.Left + _transform.X + delta.X;
        var bottomEdge = Height + Margin.Top + _transform.Y + delta.Y;

        //Set the delta to 0 if it goes over _parentGrid edges
        if (leftEdge < 0) delta.X = 0;
        if (topEdge  < 0) delta.Y = 0;

        if (rightEdge  > _parentGrid.Width)  delta.X = 0;
        if (bottomEdge > _parentGrid.Height) delta.Y = 0;

        //Apply the delta to the user control
        _transform.X += delta.X;
        _transform.Y += delta.Y;
        RenderTransform = _transform;
        _anchorPoint = _currentPoint;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a start:

```
Point position = _parentGrid.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(_parentGrid);
position = source.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice.Transform(position);
```

Now you have the screen coordinates of the parent grid. The call to `Transform()` is important as it will convert pixels to WPF device independent pixels, matching the system DPI setting.