# Get vertical offset from the top of a DataGridRow relative to top of DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How can I get the vertical offset from the `Top` of a visible `DataGridRow` relative to the `Top` of the `DataGrid` itself?

To be clear, I am not looking for the vertical offset of the row in the `ScrollViewer`.

I would like retrieve this information in the loading of rows in an attached behavior, but not sure how.

```
private void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = this.AssociatedObject;
    DataGridRow dgr = e.Row;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923697/how-can-i-get-the-position-of-a-child-element-relative-to-a-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `TranslatePoint` method:

```
private void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = this.AssociatedObject;
    DataGridRow dgr = e.Row;

    Point p = dgr.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), dg);
    double verticalDistance = p.Y;
    //...
}
```